# Are cosmetic/pharmaceutical products without parabens healthier than counterparts with it?

Tags: environmental-health, cosmetics

[Parabens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraben) are a class of preservative used in cosmetics and health related products.

A large number of products, especially for infants, claim to be free of parabens implying that this is somewhat better. An even larger number of products contain this "dreaded" parabens and I have been using them for years.

Now, with a young kid, I have been arguing with my wife about the relative merits (and have, in numerous instances, been "strongly recommended" to only buy parabens-free products). I have a suspicion that it is a marketing story, but I wonder if it can be debunked.

Are products without parabens healthier than counterparts with them?

Comment: This is my first question on skeptics.SE so I tried my best to phrase it in a fitting way. Please edit if it can be improved.

Comment: Aren't the papers cited in the Wikipedia page good enough evidence?

Comment: @nico those references are good but if I didn't miss it they are focused on possible side effects of parabens. My question is not "are parabens harmful?" But  "are parabens free products healthier? Is it recommended to use them for little babies hygiene? " it is imho slightly different.

Comment: The general idea on this website is to provide an example of the claim you want to debunk. How about citing the marketing of one of those products that claim to be good because they don't have parabens?

Comment: @Francesco: OK, got your point

Comment: If the only difference between products is that one has parabens and the other does not then the question is equivalent to "is parabens harmful?". which is probably what should be asked here.

Comment: @matt_black Since parabens are preservatives, it is possible that *other* preservatives are being added (similar to products sugar free where other kind of sweeteners can sometimes be found). That was the point of my question, but maybe I didn't formulate it clear enough.

Comment: @Francesco My first reaction on reading was exactly what matt_black commented: why not just ask straightforward if parabens are dangerous? So if you want to query "using parabens instead of other preservatives" you should edit your question and say so. *But* then the question becomes vague/broad because you do not define *other preservatives*.

Comment: @JanDoggen that could be one question but mine was a bit different. It seems to me, at least in my part of the world, that ads "imply" without stating (I suspect: because they can't) that having "0% parabens" is better. As we all know, ads typically "imply" and try to "manipulate" to put in a good light the product which is being sold. So my skepticism is related to the implication. As noted, wikipedia and other references report that parabens are not so bad after all. I wonder: what preservatives are used instead of parabens? Are they safer? That's my question. I hope that's clearer now :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. The conclusions of a report by Cosmetic Ingredient Review (CIR), a U.S.based industry-sponsored panel of experts in [2012](http://www.cir-safety.org/sites/default/files/paraben_build.pdf) states that parabens in cosmetics is safe at current exposure levels.

> The SCCS considers the use of butylparaben and propylparaben as
>   preservatives in finished cosmetic products as safe to the consumer, as long as the sum of their individual concentrations does not exceed 0.19%. This conclusion is based on the lack of scientifically sound data on the pivotal link between dermal absorption in rats and humans, in particular with regard to the metabolism of the parent compound in the skin. The latter can only be addressed through additional human data.
>
> With regard to methylparaben and ethylparaben, the previous opinion, stating that the use at the maximum authorized concentrations can be considered safe, remains unchanged.

2. There is no evidence to suggest a causal link between parabens and breast cancer per Health [Canada](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/cps-spc/cosmet-person/labelling-etiquetage/ingredients-eng.php#a4.7).
3. As of [2007](http://www.fda.gov/cosmetics/productsingredients/ingredients/ucm128042.htm), a statement by Federal Drug Agency assures that there is no reason for concern about the use of cosmetics containing parabens.

> FDA believes that at the present time there is no reason for consumers to be concerned about the use of cosmetics containing parabens. However, the agency will continue to evaluate new data in this area. If FDA determines that a health hazard exists, the agency will advise the industry and the public, and will consider its legal options under the authority of the FD&C Act in protecting the health and welfare of consumers.

4. Additional research is necessary to determine whether chemicals such as parabens can either alter the DNA in some cells or cause other breast cell changes that may lead to the development of breast cancer per [NCI](http://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/myths/antiperspirants-fact-sheet).
5. There is a need to carry out detailed evaluation of the potential for parabens per Philippa D. Darbre in [2008](http://www.theorganicpharmacy.com/Images/Content/ExpertAdvice/FactSheets/Files/107.pdf).